# how to merge two files in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I want to merge two files in Unix. How can I do this?

eg file1 contains:

```
host1:90:/users:user1 
host2:90:/users:user1 
host3:90:/users:user1 
host4:90:/users:user1
host5:90:/users:user1 
host6:90:/users:user1 
host7:90:/users:user1
```

file2 contains:

```
host1:owner_name
host2:owner_name
host3:owner_name
host4:owner_name
host5:owner_name
host6:owner_name
host7:owner_name
```

output result:

```
host1:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host2:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host3:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host4:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host5:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host6:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host7:90:/users:user1:owner_name
```

I have used this command `paste -d ':' file1 file2 >merged_file`, but this is what I am getting:

```
host1:90:/users:user1:host1:owner_name
host2:90:/users:user1:host2:owner_name
host3:90:/users:user1:host3:owner_name
host4:90:/users:user1:host4:owner_name
host5:90:/users:user1:host5:owner_name
host6:90:/users:user1:host6:owner_name
host7:90:/users:user1:host7:owner_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join` instead:

```
% join -t':' file1 file2
host1:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host2:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host3:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host4:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host5:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host6:90:/users:user1:owner_name
host7:90:/users:user1:owner_name
```

Comment: `join` works but suppose if file2 is not in sorted order then it gives error . Can we use sed or awk

Comment: @pratik That can be fixed by sorting around the first field before joining. The true question is: are you trying to just merge the files linewise or are you actually trying to join them around the first column?

Comment: i also want to merge file on first column basics .